# Dynamic relationship and the SonataAdminBundle

Tags: doctrine-orm, symfony-2.1, symfony-sonata, sonata-admin

I use the SonataAdminBundle for the first time in my life and I have some
problems with it.

At first, I had a PageBundle which has a `Page` and a `Author` entity. Then I
started using SonataAdminBundle and used the `sonata_type_model` to nicely
display the `Author`s of a `Page`:

```php
// ...

protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $mapper)
{
    $mapper
        ->add('title')
        ->add('slug', null, array('required' => false))
        ->add('published', null, array(
            'label'    => 'publish',
            'required' => false,
        ))
        ->add('author', 'sonata_type_model')
        ->add('content')
    ;
}
```

But then I discovered the SonataUserBundle. I started using it and when I
finally get it working I thought it would be nice to make use of this `User`
entity, instead of the `Author` entity in the PageBundle. To make this possible,
I used the technique where the documentation talks about in
["How to Define Relationships with Abstract Classes and Interfaces"](http://symfony.com/doc/master/cookbook/doctrine/resolve_target_entity.html).

This worked, but not with the SonataAdminBundle. It seems like the
`sonata_type_model` doesn't work with the `ResolveTargetEntityListener` and I
can't make it working.

The relevant `Page` entity code in the PageBundle:

```php
namespace Wj\PageBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
* @ORM\Table
* @ORM\Entity
* @ORM\HasLifeCycleCallbacks
*/
class Page
{
    /**
    * @var integer $authorId
    *
    * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Wj\PageBundle\Model\AuthorInterface")
    */
    private $author;
}
```

The `Wj\PageBundle\Model\AuthorInterface`:

```php
namespace Wj\PageBundle\Model;

interface AuthorInterface
{
    public function getId();
}
```

And the `User` entity in the UserBundle:

```php
namespace Wj\UserBundle\Entity;

use Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\BaseUser;
use Wj\PageBundle\Model\AuthorInterface;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
* @ORM\Entity
* @ORM\Table(name="fos_user")
*/
class User extends BaseUser implements AuthorInterface
{
    /**
    * @ORM\Id
    * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
    * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
    */
    protected $id;

    public function __toString()
    {
        return $this->getFirstName().' '.$this->getLastName();
    }
}
```

The `FormMapper` configuration is the same as I posted above.

**How can I use the ResolveTargetEntityListener technique in combination with
the SonataAdminBundle and his `sonata_type_model`?**

Comment: did you configure the listener the config.yml file?